# Destroy method does not work, instead show method implements (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods

I need to make a button to destroy object.
Instead of destroy it shows fields

inex.html.erb

```
<%= link_to image_tag("/images/glossy_green_button.png"), device , { :html => { :method =>  :delete}, :controller => :devices, :action => 'destroy',:id => device.id, :onclick => 'return confirm(\'Are you sure?\');' }, :method => :turnon %>
```

devices_controller.rb

```
def destroy
 @device = Device.find(params[:id])
 @device.destroy

  respond_to do |format|
   format.html { render action: "destroy" }
   format.json { head :no_content }
  end
 end
```

routes.rb

```
device GET    /devices/:id(.:format)      devices#show
       PUT    /devices/:id(.:format)      devices#update
       DELETE /devices/:id(.:format)      devices#destroy
```

Appreciate any ideas what I got wrong.
Thank you
D

UPDATED:

```
<%= button_to "Delete", device ,  :method => :delete %>
```

this works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Destructive actions should be performed as a form submission - http://www.w3.org/2001/tag/doc/whenToUseGet.html#checklist

use button_to (passing a :method of :delete) instead and style the button appropriately.

or Try this `<%= button_to "delete", your_object, :method=>:delete, :class=>:destroy %>`

Comment: It works but now it won't ask "are you sure?" `<%= button_to "delete", device, :method=>:delete, :class=>:destroy, :confirm => "Are you shore?" %>`

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to

Answer (score 3):

Which version of Rails are you using? Why your `link_to` method calling is so complex? It can be simply re-written. Try the following one:

```
<%= link_to image_tag("/images/glossy_green_button.png"), device , :method => :delete,  :confirm => "Are you sure?"
```

Comment: Rails version 3.2.8, so complicated because trying everything to make it work, a bit desperate, I know ...

Comment: Your answer still shows only no delete, also  `:confirm => "Are you sure?"` got broken for some reason

`<%= link_to image_tag("/images/glossy_green_button.png"), device , {:onclick => 'return confirm(\'Are you sure?\');' }, :method => :delete %>` that is simplified but still does not work .

Comment: Maybe problem is in image_tag?

Comment: what is the problem now? show us the markup that is generated.

Comment: Problem the same it do show method , instead of delete method. SO it show all the fields of Device with buttons "Edit" and "Back"

Comment: Do you have 'jquery_ujs' enabled in your javascript manifest file?

Comment: No Idea, there was a typo in application.html.erb, now it is working